# Only strip commas surrounded by numbers in a string

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

I am using StreamReader to read each line of a CSV file into a string.  As I am processing each line, I need to strip out any commas that ONLY are surrounded by other numbers.

For example, if the string was:

`"textfield1", "textfield2", "100.00", "1,070.00"`

I would need to only take the comma out of "1,070.00" from this entire string, resulting in:

`"textfield1", "textfield2", "100.00", "1070.00"`

Each string read from the CSV file can differ in number of fields, length, etc.,  so I need to use something (Regular Expressions maybe?) that looks at the entire string without hardcoding a location or blanket removal of all commas.

Here is the approach I have been trying:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strInputFile);
string nextLine = sr.ReadLine();     

try
{
    while ((nextLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string rawtext = nextLine.Replace("[0-9]"+","+"[0-9]" , "[0-9]"+"[0-9]");

        // ....rest of code
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because I don't understand how to do this :)
I am new at C# and inexperienced in Regex, so hopefully this is relatively simple.

Comment: The problem you're having is that `"1,070.00"` is becoming `"[0-9][0-9]70.00"`, right? just to make sure that we're going to answer the right question.

Comment: Also you don't have to append `"[0-9]" + "," + "[0-9]"` like that. You can write a single string: `"[0-9],[0-9]"`. Even if you keep doing it as you're doing, though, the compiler will see that they're fixed strings and will make it one string only in the assembly.

Comment: Any reason why you're not just doing a `Decimal.TryParse`?

Comment: If you're reading a CSV, you probably should be using `TextFieldParser`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a regular expression:

```
string rawtext = Regex.Replace(nextLine, @"(\d),(\d)", "$1$2");
```

Or this equivalent pattern:

```
string rawtext = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\d),(?=\d)", "");
```